# how to Invoke User-Defined Functions That Return a Table Data Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

here my code-

```
create function dbo.emptable()
returns Table
as
return (select id, name, salary from employee)
go

select dbo.emptable()
```

**error:** Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.emptable", or the name is ambiguous.

while when I run
    `sp_helptext emptable`
it shows-

```
create function dbo.emptable()  
returns Table  
as  
return (select id, name, salary from employee)
```

**it means function exists in database then why it is giving such error?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because when you select from the function you need to say

```
select * from dbo.emptable()
```

not

```
select dbo.emptable()
```

Answer (score 1):

`select * from dbo.emptable()`

It's a table, after all...